# Bootstrap dropdown menu width with right-aligned glyphicons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu from the navbar and it has right-aligned (css class pull-right) glyphicons. One of the menu items is a bit longer than the others and it runs into the glyphicon, causing it to be moved down a half-line:

[image]

I can obviously set the width of this dropdown manually with a CSS class and a hardcoded width, but I'd rather get Bootstrap to incorporate the glyphicon width appropriately. How do I need to structure my HTML or what changes to CSS do I need to make to make this work?

Here's the HTML for the entire navbar:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <span>
                <img id="XXX-brand-logo" alt="Brand" src="/Content/Images/XXX.png" width="20" height="20"></span>
            Home
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li>
                <a href="/XXX">XXX</a>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">XXX<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/XXX">XXX</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/XXX">XXX</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">XXX<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/XXX/XXX">XXX</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/XXX/XXX">XXX</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Admin<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/Admin/Role/ManageRoles">Manage Roles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Admin/Group/ManageGroups">Manage Groups</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Admin/User/ManageUsers">Manage Users</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Administrator<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/Account/Account/Settings">Settings <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench pull-right"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Account/Account/ChangePassword">Change Password <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock pull-right"></span></a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/Account/Login/Logout">Logout <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out pull-right"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's any CSS that could possible modify this page:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.glyphicon-hover {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 2px;
}

.glyphicon-hover:hover, .glyphicon:focus {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: red;
}
```

I'm using jquery-ui.css (version 1.11.4 via jQuery.UI.Combined in Nuget) and  bootstrap.css (version 3.3.6.1 via Nuget).

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of  ```.dropdown``` to something like 100% via CSS?

Comment: When I replicate your code on http://www.bootply.com I can't seem to reproduce the issue, the menu expands to accommodate the length of the list item text. It seems to me though that you have some sort of width constraint applied to that menu, and that setting the width to `auto` should resolve this.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError: I added the entire HTML for my navbar in the question body. I also put in some CSS and version numbers. Hope that will help you diagnose. I can't see any CSS that should set the width of the menu and chrome's inspector shows auto for the menu's LIs and the containing UL. The containing LI in the navbar does have a smaller width, but that's the menu header.

Comment: @siride Thanks! That helped a lot.If you can shift around elements and wrap the link text in tags I'm sure the following example could work for you: http://www.bootply.com/wMD9IaHs4R 

Alternatively, you could also try adding the icons in as pseudo elements of the link tag itself, then position them `absolute` and set them accordingly with `top`, `right`, etc

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError: make that an answer and you'll get some karma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearranging your markup to place the icon before the anchor text (this will circumvent the "step-down" effect), then wrapping the anchor text in another nested tag that you can target to apply further styling will help in resolving the issue at hand.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu ">
  <li><a href="/Account/Account/Settings "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench pull-right "></span><span class="dropdown-link-text ">Settings</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/Account/Account/ChangePassword "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock pull-right "></span><span class="dropdown-link-text ">Change Password</span></a>
  </li>
  <li role="separator " class="divider "></li>
  <li><a href="/Account/Login/Logout "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out pull-right "></span><span class="dropdown-link-text ">Logout</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-link-text {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Working example: http://www.bootply.com/wMD9IaHs4R

Alternatively, you could also try adding the icons in as pseudo elements of the link tag itself, then position them `absolute` and adjust the `top`, `right` values accordingly.

Comment: That did the trick! I'll probably adjust the right margin a little bit for more space, though.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this CSS instead of the `.pull-right` class:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    padding-right: 46px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu > li > a > .glyphicon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 5px;
  }
}
```

Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.glyphicon-hover {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 2px;
}

.glyphicon-hover:hover, .glyphicon:focus {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    padding-right: 46px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu > li > a > .glyphicon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <span>
                <img id="XXX-brand-logo" alt="Brand" src="/Content/Images/XXX.png" width="20" height="20"></span>
            Home
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li>
                <a href="/XXX">XXX</a>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">XXX<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/XXX">XXX</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/XXX">XXX</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">XXX<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/XXX/XXX">XXX</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/XXX/XXX">XXX</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Admin<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/Admin/Role/ManageRoles">Manage Roles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Admin/Group/ManageGroups">Manage Groups</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Admin/User/ManageUsers">Manage Users</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Administrator<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/Account/Account/Settings"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Account/Account/ChangePassword"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>Change Password</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/Account/Login/Logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to line break the text

```
Change<br>Password
```

This leaves all elements and the menu the same size horizontally. The second simple solution is to change the width

```
.glyphicon {
  padding-left: 10px;    
}
```

Comment: The first change is undesirable and the second makes no difference.